# How to display record inside form Access 2016 - VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hope you're enjoying your Friday afternoon!

I've got a form on MS Access which searches a linked table for a barcode (which is entered by the user) 
If the barcode exists in the table I'd like to show the user the record which contains the matched barcode, if not the code moves on elsewhere.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "Query2"

    Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("Query2", s)

    Me.sbfMatchedRec.SourceObject = "Query2"
```

I get an error when trying to change the SourceObject to Query2.
If I open Query2 it has the exact information I need in it.  I can also go via the form properties and change the SourceObject to Query2 which then displays what I need, but I just need to know how to change this in VBA as above.

Thanks!

Comment: Which subform event is this VBA written on?

Comment: Also, shouldn't a SourceObject be a form or report, rather than query?

Comment: I have only one unbound form, I just want the VBA to build the query (based on the barcode the user enters) then to set that query data to display inside the form.  Maybe I have gone the wrong way about this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply HansUp, have got this working now! All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could requery the subform with the barcode passed in from the form's textbox as the `WHERE` criteria in the subform's `.RecordSource` property.

For example, say this table (**tblProducts**) has your list of barcoded records:

[image]

You could then add a subform to your form that will show records from **tblProducts**. Also add a textbox to the form for the user to supply a barcode and a command button for the user to initiate a search:

[image]

Before hooking-up the search button with the VBA, take a look at the `.RecordSource` property for the subform...

[image]

...switch the query builder to SQL View:

[image]

Copy the sql as you can use this as the basis to filter the records in the subform using VBA.

Go back to the form in design view and go in to the search button's On Click event:

[image]

The SQL you've copied can then be used to create an SQL string that takes the value entered in the form's barcode textbox (I've called the text box on the form *txtBarcode*) as part of the `WHERE` clause. This sql string can then be applied to the subform's `.RecordSource` property and then the subform can be requeried to show the result set of the new SQL definition in the subform:

```vb
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "SELECT tblProducts.Barcode, tblProducts.ProductName" _
           & " FROM tblProducts"

    If _
        Me.txtBarcode > "" _
    Then
        strSql = strSql & " WHERE tblProducts.Barcode=" & Me.txtBarcode
    End If

    Me.tblProducts_sub.Form.RecordSource = strSql
    Me.tblProducts_sub.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

So if we put `1001` in the text box on the form, and click the search button, the subfom only shows that matching record:

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed thanks so much for an incredibly informative post.  I hope you have a great weekend!

Comment: P.S Great product names! Made me chuckle!

Comment: Thanks! glad to have helped :)